# Angular mat slider not working properly when used with *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend, material-design

my problem is pretty straight forward as I could reproduce it over stackblitz.

If I use multiple mat sliders created from a *ngFor list with contains numbers for the sliders values, at the moment of catching the "input" event the sliders won't work as expected, sliding the very first one will cause to move every other slider, but just of the first drag, on the followings, only the first slider will update, however, I'm not able to move it freely, when I try to drag the slider with the mouse it just stops after moving a little bit.

I have no clue why this happens,if I render the matsliders manually (not using ngFor) everything work as expected, but I see nothing wrong with the *ngFor and I actually need to render sliders dynamically on my actual project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvduws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider-configurable-example.html

Any help will be really appreciated. I'm using Google Chrome, Angular 11 and Angular Material 11.2.12

Edit: If I try to use the "s" local variable to change the values angular will throw the following error "Cannot use variable 's' as the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Template variables are read-only.", this do not happen in stackblitz, no clue why either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using `let i = index` and `index[i]`, when you have `s`. I'm honestly not sure *why* this is happening, but this seems to resolve it:

```
<div *ngFor="let s of list; let i = index">
  <mat-slider [(ngModel)]="list[i]"> </mat-slider>
  {{ s }}
</div>
```

Comment: It truly solve it, thank you very much, I actually got my mind blocked and ignored that the element was stored as "s"

Comment: Actually, once I implemented over my Angular project I received the following error: "Cannot use variable 's' as the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Template variables are read-only." I looked over the internet and seems like ngFor local variables are readonly, don't know why stackblitz let's us assign it

Comment: I updated my answer. It's been a while since I did angular :) This was helpful - https://v7.material.angular.io/components/slider/examples

Comment: For the record, I'm using angular 11, and with your solution I still receive the message "Cannot use variable 's' as the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Template variables are read-only.", however, it let me to the right direction, I just used [(ngModel)]="list[i]" and it worked as expected, please, update your answer to that, so I can give you the bounty, and thank you